# For mxmlc (flex flash compiler), what is the target player if no -target-player is set?

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I'd like to know what the target-player is for a given flex sdk 3.2, 3.5, and 4.6 if no -target-player command line option is specified.

I would think it would be the minimum version supported by the sdk, but I can't find any documentation to confirm.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_01.html):

> If you do not explicitly set the value of this option, the compiler
>   uses the default from the flex-config.xml file. The value in
>   flex-config.xml is the version of Flash Player that shipped with the
>   SDK.

I'm pretty sure the flex-config.xml file should be somewhere in the SDK directory.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your answer helped me double as I failed to find anything in the docs initially. The search took me out of the docs, and I missed a topic expansion. The parent just sent me to mxclmc -help to look for the options, and I overlooked that it had children.